# Can i use mysql with yii framework?

Tags: mysql, yii

I have xampp installed which includes mysql. Can i use this mysql with yii framework? 
If yes how can i do it with phpmyadmin. Pls help. Am a newbie..

I have seen many people using sqlite with yii in many tutorials..

Comment: please do some basic research first.

Comment: http://indev.org.ua/download/Larry_Ullman_The_Yii_Book_2013_www.indev.org.ua.pdf refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok what you need to do is open `/protected/config/main.php`, and look for the line like this :

```
            ),
    'db'=>array( // as you can see this db is currently in use
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:protected/data/blog.db',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
    /*
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),
    */
```

just comment the first connection to sqlite data base and uncomment the second part that uses mysql database :

```
            ),
    /*'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:protected/data/blog.db',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),*/
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),
```

that's all!

Comment: Thank you very much.. Can u tell me how can i display database contents to a page..? For example in index.php...

Comment: http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/05/creating-models-views-and-controllers-in-yii/ these link help You

Comment: I think you need to research more and maybe read a book on Yii, these all are well explained there.